# Missing option for C# but only F# when creating new ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller) template in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, f#, asp.net-core-mvc

The problem is that C# option is missing when creating new ASP.NET Core Web App (MVC) template. I've done VS repair and reinstallation of ASP.NET but it did not help.

Windows 10 Pro 21H2
Visual Studio 2019 (latest version)

[image: Screen on creation window]

Comment: Um, maybe look at the fourth project template in the screenshot you posted.

Comment: Also, if you want to create a project in a specific language then you should make a selection in the language drop-down, rather than leaving "All languages" selected. You probably wouldn't have made the error in the first place if you had done that. Probably make selections in the other two drop-downs too. I would recommend ALWAYS using them to filter and then use the box at the top last, only where necessary, e.g. I normally only use it to filter out non-Framework projects.